# How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a need to add or prepend elements at the beginning of an array.

For example, if my array looks like below:

```
[23, 45, 12, 67]
```

And the response from my AJAX call is `34`, I want the updated array to be like the following:

```
[34, 23, 45, 12, 67]
```

Currently I am planning to do it like this:

```
var newArray = [];
newArray.push(response);

for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(theArray[i]);
}

theArray = newArray;
delete newArray;
```

Is there a better way to do this? Does JavaScript have any built-in functionality that does this?

The complexity of my method is `O(n)` and it would be really interesting to see better implementations.

Comment: FYI: If you need to continuously insert an element at the beginning of an array, it is faster to use `push` statements followed by a call to `reverse`, instead of calling `unshift` all the time.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly you should post this as an answer. Matched my use-case perfectly. thanks

Comment: Performance tests:
https://jsperf.com/adding-element-to-the-array-start

But the results are different for each browser.

Answer (score 3904, accepted):

Use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). It's like [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), except it adds elements to the beginning of the array instead of the end.

- `unshift`/`push` - add an element to the beginning/end of an array
- `shift`/`pop`  - remove and return the first/last element of an array

A simple diagram...

```
unshift -> [array] <- push
shift   <- [array] -> pop
```

and chart:

|  | add | remove | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `push` | X |  |  | X |
| `pop` |  | X |  | X |
| `unshift` | X |  | X |  |
| `shift` |  | X | X |  |

Check out the [MDN Array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Virtually every language that has the ability to push/pop elements from an array will also have the ability to unshift/shift (sometimes called `push_front`/`pop_front`) elements, you should never have to implement these yourself.

---

As pointed out in the comments, if you want to avoid mutating your original array, you can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which concatenates two or more arrays together. You can use this to functionally push a single element onto the front or back of an existing array; to do so, you need to turn the new element into a single element array:

```js
const array = [3, 2, 1]

const newFirstElement = 4

const newArray = [newFirstElement].concat(array) // [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

console.log(newArray);
```

`concat` can also append items. The arguments to `concat` can be of any type; they are implicitly wrapped in a single-element array, if they are not already an array:

```js
const array = [3, 2, 1]

const newLastElement = 0

// Both of these lines are equivalent:
const newArray1 = array.concat(newLastElement) // [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
const newArray2 = array.concat([newLastElement]) // [ 3, 2, 1, 0 ]

console.log(newArray1);
console.log(newArray2);
```

Comment: Using `concat` might be preferable as it returns the new array. Very useful for chaining.  `[thingToInsertToFront].concat(originalArray).reduce(fn).reverse().map(fn)` etc...
If you use `unshift`, you can't do that chaining because all you get back is the length.

Comment: shift/unshift, push/pop, splice. Very logical names for such methods.

Answer (score 1727):

[image: array operations image]

```js
var a = [23, 45, 12, 67];
a.unshift(34);
console.log(a); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67]
```

Comment: The reason why people need a visual guideline for 4 everyday used functions is because of the encrypted function names... Why is unshift not called Insert? Shift should be Remove. etc...

Comment: **//Why is unshift not called Insert?//** It comes from the conventions of the C programming language where array elements were treated like a stack. (see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=613129 for a complete explanation)

Comment: @Pascal No, insert and remove would be particularly bad names for this; they imply random access, instead of adding/removing from the front of the array

Comment: I would have thought that unshift should remove the first key, and shift would insert at the first key, but that's just my general thought

Comment: Mind that `[23, 45, 12, 67].unshift(34)` will not work. The Array **must** first be saved inside a variable, because `unshift` **itself** returns a value.

Answer (score 363):

#### With ES6, use the spread operator `...`:

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [23, 45, 12, 67];
arr = [34, ...arr]; // RESULT : [34,23, 45, 12, 67]

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: also creates a new array, useful for pure functions

Comment: what is the performance implication here? Is it slower than using unshift()?

Comment: Sure, it will be slower since it is an immutable array ( creating a new array). If you are working with a big array or the performance is your first requirement, please consider to use `concat` instead.

Comment: performance is not important in 2018, new versions in browser and node get the same performance

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI Just to clarify your comment. It is not creating an immutable array, it is just creating a new array without mutating the existing one.

Comment: @stackdave Of **_course_** performance is important in 2018 (2022). It may not be important in your todo app or webshop UI with 20 elements, but it's important in my graphics editor with 500 MB typed arrays.

Answer (score 93):

Another way to do that is through `concat`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
console.log([0].concat(arr));
```

The difference between `concat` and `unshift` is that `concat` returns a new array. The performance between them could be found [here](http://jsperf.com/unshift-item-inside-an-array/12).

```
function fn_unshift() {
  arr.unshift(0);
  return arr;
}

function fn_concat_init() {
  return [0].concat(arr)
}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: It would be good for your answer to append the performance comparison of both apart from adding the reference.

Comment: I just got _jsPerf is temporarily unavailable while we’re working on releasing v2. Please try again later_ from the link. Another good reason to include the results instead of linking to them.

Comment: **jsPref** result:  

`unshift`: 25,510 ±3.18% 99% slower  

`concat`: 2,436,894 ±3.39% fastest

Comment: In the latest Safari, fn_unshift() runs faster.

Comment: In the latest Safari (v 10), fn_unshift() is slower again.

Answer (score 53):

**Quick Cheatsheet:**

The terms shift/unshift and push/pop can be a bit confusing, at least to folks who may not be familiar with programming in C.

If you are not familiar with the lingo, here is a quick translation of alternate terms, which may be easier to remember:

```
* array_unshift()  -  (aka Prepend ;; InsertBefore ;; InsertAtBegin )     
* array_shift()    -  (aka UnPrepend ;; RemoveBefore  ;; RemoveFromBegin )

* array_push()     -  (aka Append ;; InsertAfter   ;; InsertAtEnd )     
* array_pop()      -  (aka UnAppend ;; RemoveAfter   ;; RemoveFromEnd )
```

Answer (score 37):

Using ES6 [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) (avoiding mutation off the original array):

`const newArr = [item, ...oldArr]`

Comment: Essentially a duplicate answer of [the one by Abdennour TOUMI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39531492/1578604)...

Answer (score 26):

You have an array:  `var arr = [23, 45, 12, 67];`

To add an item to the beginning, you want to use `splice`:

```js
var arr = [23, 45, 12, 67];
arr.splice(0, 0, 34)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: arr.splice(0, arr.length, 34);

Comment: @LiorElrom what does your snippet do?

Comment: @poushy it's browser specific, in Firefox 54 is `unshift` 50% faster (but mostly more readable)

Comment: @poushy Not anymore. Way slower.

Answer (score 26):

**Without Mutating**

Actually, all `unshift`/`push` and `shift`/`pop` **mutate** the source array.

The `unshift`/`push` add an item to the existed array from begin/end and `shift`/`pop` remove an item from the beginning/end of an array.

But there are few ways to add items to an array without a mutation. the result is a new array, to add to the end of array use below code:

```
const originArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const newItem = 4;

const newArray = originArray.concat(newItem); // ES5
const newArray2 = [...originArray, newItem]; // ES6+
```

To add to begin of original array use below code:

```
const originArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const newItem = 0;

const newArray = (originArray.slice().reverse().concat(newItem)).reverse(); // ES5
const newArray2 = [newItem, ...originArray]; // ES6+
```

With the above way, you add to the beginning/end of an array without a mutation.

Comment: I just put an `slice` function at the end of `originArray` to prevent it from mutability.

Comment: Awesome! When comes to (Redux) State management... this answer is precious!

Comment: [newItem, ...originArray]; // ES6+ Is great syntax ! Worked perfect  !! thanks.

Answer (score 18):

**Cheatsheet to prepend new element(s) into the array**

**1. [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)**

```js
const list = [23, 45, 12, 67];

list.unshift(34);

console.log(list); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67];
```

**2. [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

```js
const list = [23, 45, 12, 67];

list.splice(0, 0, 34);

console.log(list); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67];
```

**3. [ES6 spread...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

```js
const list = [23, 45, 12, 67];
const newList = [34, ...list];

console.log(newList); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67];
```

**4. [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)**

```js
const list = [23, 45, 12, 67];
const newList = [32].concat(list);

console.log(newList); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67];
```

**Note:** In each of these examples, you can prepend multiple items by providing more items to insert.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to continuously insert an element at the beginning of an array, it is faster to use `push` statements followed by a call to `reverse`, instead of calling `unshift` all the time.

**Benchmark test:** http://jsben.ch/kLIYf

Comment: Note: initial array should be empty.

Comment: In 2021 your benchmark shows a comprehensive win for `unshift` across all major desktop browsers (at least on this Mac).

Comment: @OllyHodgson testing on Ubuntu Linux with Firefox: reverse solution is 3-times faster.

Answer (score 8):

Using `splice` we insert an element to an array at the begnning:

```js
arrName.splice( 0, 0, 'newName1' );
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to push elements that are in an array at the beginning of your array, use `<func>.apply(<this>, <Array of args>)`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
arr.unshift.apply(arr, [3, 4]);
console.log(arr); // [3, 4, 1, 2]
```