# how to insert object into beginning of object list, when it has unshift is not a function error?

Tags: javascript

How to insert object element in object which is list of object ?

I have this tiny piece of code in ReactJS:

```
var allMessages = this.state.data;
var newMessages = allMessages.unshift([data]); // i suppose it should be unshift if it was an array, but it is an object o_O
this.setState({ data: newMessages });
```

Where:
(chrome console output)

```
> data
Object {id: "12", text: "1234124", date: "2016-04-28 20:00:07", sender: "user", type: "receiver"}
> allMessages
[Array[1], Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
> typeof allMessages
"object"
```

How to insert `data` into beginning of `allMessages` ?

I have seen this reply [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript) and it is another case because my `allMessages` variable is an `object` not an Array.

I got `unshift is not a function` when i try to use `unshift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(allMessages);
arr.unshift(data);
```

You can see [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of this work around;

```
var tempMessage= {};
tempMessage.data = data;
for(var key in allMessages){
     tempMessage[key] = allMessages[key];
}
```

Than just set it back

```
allMessages = tempMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacky business but for me the following did it:

```
this.setState({data: this.state.data.reverse().concat(data).reverse()});
```

So basically change the order put it in last and change the order again, ugly I know but it does work.