# Google Sheets: How do I add a value at the start of a 1x2 array and shift everything right?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script editor, I have the code:

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Stock History");
  var source = sheet.getRange("B2:C2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][2] = values[0][1];
  values[0][1] = values[0][0];
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

What is the correct way to shunt `values[0][0]` & `values[0][1]` into `values[0][1]` & `values[0][2]` so I don't have to use:

```
  values[0][2] = values[0][1];
  values[0][1] = values[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript so you could use the JavaScript array methods to achieve your goal, like [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

## References

[How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values.unshift(new Date());
```

It will add elements to the beginning of an array.

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.