# How to add new node at top in ui-tree angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-tree

In my application i used angular ui-tree.

Now to add new node i used below code

```
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-sm" type="button" ng-click='x.tasks.push({task: "New Task",depth:"2", tasks:[]})' style="margin-top:15px" data-nodrag><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
                            <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">

                                <div style="width:100%">
                                    <div style="width:87%;display: inline-block">
                                        <a class="" style="color:#c1c1c1" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-plus': collapsed, 'fa-minus': !collapsed}"></span>
                                            <span class="label label-info"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i></span> </a>
                                            <span style="width:80%;word-wrap: break-word" class="remove-editable-click cursor-pointer" editable-text="node.task" buttons="no" e-ng-model="WBSData.task" e-ng-blur="changeFieldEdit(this)" e-required data-nodrag e-style="border:1px solid #DDDDDD;width:90px">
                                               {{node.task}}
                                            </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="width:10%;display: inline-block">
                                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="node.WBSDataSelectedTask" checklist-value="node.task" style="float:right" value="none">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.subtasks" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                                <li ng-repeat="node in node.subtasks" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer1.html'">
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </script>
                        <div ui-tree="treeOptions" id="tree-root">

                            <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="x.tasks">
                                <li ng-repeat="node in x.tasks" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
```

By clicking on button it is adding node but adding node at bottom.I need to add that on top.How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.task.push` adds item at the end of the array. That's where you need to change

```
ng-click='x.tasks.push({task: "New Task",depth:"2", tasks:[]})'
```

Use `unshift` instead.

```
ng-click='x.tasks.unshift({task: "New Task",depth:"2", tasks:[]})'
```

For reference: [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)