# Add object to the beginning of array using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, spread-syntax

I have an array like this:

```
var oldArray = [{'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, {'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
```

what I want is using spread operator add a new object at the beginning of that array:

BTW this works:

```
var oldArray = [{'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, {'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
var newObj = {'value': 'all', 'label': 'all'}
var result = [newObj, ...oldArray]
```

But generates a key "newObj" like this:

```
var oldArray = [newObj : {'value': 'all', 'label': 'all'}, 0: {'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, 1:{'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
```

And I want the key to be auto generated like if I do this:

```
var result = [{'value': 'all', 'label': 'all'}, ...oldArray]
```

And imagine the result is this:

```
var oldArray = [newObj : {0: 'all', 'label': 'all'}, 1: {'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, 2:{'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
```

but that gives me an error.

Right now I'm using unshift and it works, I wonder if there's a way to do the same with spread operator.

Comment: Can you not just use [`unshift()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)?

Comment: your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: `var result = [newObj, ...oldArray]` also gives the correct output. am i missing something ?

Comment: So many answers suggesting unshift but that is not what you asked. `var result = [newObj, ...oldArray]` _does_ work and is the right answer, the problem is you have a false premise in your question...

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've said that var result = [newObj, ...oldArray] works and unshift works is what I've used. But I'm using a drop down library that takes the resulting array to generate the drop down, and result = [newObj, ...oldArray] generates a key value that brokes the library. I've corrected the question removing the false premise.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a little late but

You can solve this problem modifying it like this with spreed:

change:

```
var result = [newObj, ...oldArray]
```

for:

```
var result = [{...newObj}, ...oldArray]
```

Comment: it will show `[{}, oldArray]` if newObj is empty.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [***`unshift()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) function which does exactly that:

```
let oldArray = [{'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, {'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
let newObj = {'value': 'all', 'label': 'all'}
oldArray.unshift(newObj)

console.log(oldArray)
```

Or if you don't want to modify the original array, you can do:

```
const result = oldArray.slice()
result.unshift(newObj)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `unshift()`? It seems to work as shown in George's code snippet in his answer below.  Why the -1?  Is there a drawback to using unshift? (Edit:) oh, because it's not using the spread operator as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @downvoter Could've mentioned that w/o the downvote... SO becomes a more hostile site day by day.

Comment: You did not answer the question asked.

Comment: @AP. Yes, SO/SE are known to be very hostile, everywhere on the Internet people talk about the negativity here. I agree. Downvoting, downvoting, downvoting, sometimes for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unshift()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) to add items to the beginning of an array

```js
var oldArray = [{'value': '1', 'label': 'a'}, {'value': '2', 'label': 'b'}]
var newObj = {'value': 'all', 'label': 'all'}
oldArray.unshift(newObj);

console.log(oldArray);
```