# how to prepend new item to array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

i need to prepend value in typescript objects array

Example if array is

```
[
   {'title':'this is post title1','content':'this is post content1'},
   {'title':'this is post title2','content':'this is post content2'},
   {'title':'this is post title3','content':'this is post content3'},
   {'title':'this is post title4','content':'this is post content4'},
   {'title':'this is post title5','content':'this is post content5'},
]
```

i want when i put new item in the first of this array like prepend in jQuery

```
[
   {'title':'this is new item title','content':'this is new item content'},
   {'title':'this is post title1','content':'this is post content1'},
   {'title':'this is post title2','content':'this is post content2'},
   {'title':'this is post title3','content':'this is post content3'},
   {'title':'this is post title4','content':'this is post content4'},
   {'title':'this is post title5','content':'this is post content5'},
]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Same way as in JS. `typescript` tag is for TS-specific questions.

Comment: **.unshift()**

TypeScript is a syntactic sugar of JavaScript.
So You should google JavaScript a https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/unshift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: The example you gave is javascript. You should create a class in typescript for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done with jquery, because it is functionality belongs to the javascript array object.

You could use the array function [`unshift()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) for that.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `unshift` to prepend items to an array:

```
const myArray = [ 2, 3, 4 ]

myArray.unshift(1)

console.log(myArray); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

You can find the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `...` operator

Eg :

```
 let myArray = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ];
 myArray = [0, ...myArray];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with splice.

```
arr.splice(index, 0, item);
```

[From another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index)