# Limit mongoose schema length

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I limit mongoose schema length, remove the first/oldest item from the schema when it reaches the limit and appends the new value to the schema?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  Posts: { type: Object }
  Date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

As you can see above in the code, I have Posts schema, it accepts items with no limit, but let's say I want to limit it with 50 posts when a user adds more than 50 posts it should automatically delete/remove the first item and save the newest post.

Comment: So you want to create a FIFO (First in First out) data structure?

Comment: hey there, are you sure this is correct ` Posts: { type: Array }`? array of what?

Comment: @JorgePires an array of posts, Posts: [
        { _id: xxxxxx..., postType: 2, imgurl: 'http://url-to-image', caption: 'lorem ipsum.'},
        { _id: xxxxxx..., postType: 4, txt: 'lorem ipsum...'},
.... [upto 50 items]
]

Comment: A I have added a solution, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I couldn't find any MongoDB way of solving it. here's what I did to achieve this:

```
function newPost(post, limit) {
  Post.find({}, {}, { sort: { Date: 1 } }).then(resp => {
    if (resp.length < limit) {
      new Post(post).save();
    } else {
      Post.findByIdAndRemove(resp[0]._id).exec().catch(err => { throw err });
      new Post(post).save();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: your solution does not seem to create the bubble effect, what happens to the movement between first and last?

Comment: Now I got it! you wanted to sort by date, but I believe the effect will be the same, no? if the order is FIFO. so it does not matter the date!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you are right, and I saw you updated the question as well. I am glad things worked out just fine aftermath!

Answer (score 1):

Call a function after defining your model in mongoose. You should look up virtual functions in mongoose l,  they get invoked after every change in you document.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my solution for String, you must adapt for your case. 
For the sake of simplicity, my vector is limited to 3, your case 50, just change the code!

```
require("./connection");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  User: String,
  Posts: [String] //since I am not familar with the notation { type: Array }, I have decided to work with something I am familiar with
});

PostSchema.virtual("posts").set(function(newPost) {
  if (this.Posts.length >= 3) {//change here the size to 50
    this.Posts.pop();
    this.Posts.unshift(newPost);
  } else {
    this.Posts.unshift(newPost);
  }
});

Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

Post.findOne({ User: "Jorge Pires" }).then(post => {
  post.posts = "this is nice!";
  post.save();
  console.log(post);
});

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//uncomment for creating your first dataset sample
// Post.create({
//   User: "Jorge Pires",
//   Posts: ["Hey there", "I am on stack overflow", "this is nice"]
// });
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

*How it works?*

The new elements will enter in the back, and the oldest will be removed if the vector size exceed its limit, mine 3 and yours 50. 
It creates the "bubble effect", as you introduce new elements, the oldest ones automatically will move to the head and be eliminated eventually.

**references**

- [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)
- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals