# When I iterate an array in Javascript when push it always return last index in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an array with a unique Id, every time I push the id in the array is always the last index.
This is the code I have tried:

```
locationData.forEach((data,index) => {
      if(1==data.id){
      data.uniqId= index
      myArray.push(data)                     
   }                 
});
```

What I get:

```
[{uniqId:3},[{uniqId:3},[{uniqId:3}]
```

What I want

```
[{uniqId:1},[{uniqId:2},[{uniqId:3}]
```

Comment: the `push()` method inserts the new element at the end of the array. [Are you trying to add a new item to the start of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: No, what I want is that the first element gets the id of 1 the second index gets the id of 2  etc... the result I get now is all the elements have the last index as the id.

What I get:[{uniqId:3},[{uniqId:3},[{uniqId:3}]
What I want: [{uniqId:1},[{uniqId:2},[{uniqId:3}]

Comment: @JosephCastillo What's that `if` condition doing there? Can you simply do this?
`locationData.forEach((data,index) => {
      myArray.push({uniqueId: index+1});            
});`

Comment: I'm not sure "what you're getting" is correct since your output mentions only "uniqueId" whereas your `data`, from the code you've written, seems to contain a field `id` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having is that instead of creating a Deep copy I was just creating a variable, 
I did this to fix it:

```
locationData =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationData))
```

and after that run through the array. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me if locationData is an array containing objects with the property "id".

```js
var locationData = [{id: 1},{id:1}];
var myArray = [];
locationData.forEach((data,index) => {
      if(1==data.id){
      data.uniqId= index + 1
      myArray.push(data)                     
   }                 
});
console.log(myArray)
```

If your locationData has some nested things, you may have to flatten the array:

```
var locationData = [[{id: 1},{id:1}], {id:2}];
locationData = locationData.flat(1);
```