# how to update useState() and push to first position?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Using `const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])` I can update projects, but how can I push to projects at the first position?

I am using

```
setProjects([...projects, newData])
```

but that adds the newData at the end. I want it to be at the first position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new array elements at the beginning of an array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/39531492/3001761, I'm surprised to didn't guess it from what you have.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now, where I got the answer, me neighter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there -

```
setProjects([newData, ...projects])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setProjects([newData, ...projects ])
```