# How could i enter an item at the start of an Uint8Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, bson

is it possible to somehow take this code
and enter `'a'` at the start of `data`?

```js
const BSON = require('bson');
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8876");
var json = {
  'username':this.name,
  'email':this.email,
  'password':this.password,

}
const data = new Uint8Array(BSON.serialize(json).buffer)
```

Comment: its literally called typed array why do you want to add a character to an integer array ?

Comment: it's just an example, I am just asking how to enter anything in the start of the array

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073673/how-can-i-add-new-array-elements-at-the-beginning-of-an-array-in-javascript